# Sql server 2012 evaluation in Windows Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure

Can anyone tell me what is the limitations of this version like some features not to be supported or something.
I am going to create this type of Windows Azure VM for my application.
The full control of sql and Compatibility is my first consideration.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server 2012 running in Windows AzureVM is exact version which you have installed by your own and the only difference is that it is evaluation version so you can try it before make it final. Once you have tried it and know this is what you want, you can have your own SQL Server 2012 running on a VM you could create to fit your need.

Comment: Is it used for free ? I mean should I be charged for both Windows Azure VM and SQl server 2012 evaluation Cost according to the Microsoft azure price policy? Or only for the VM? Thanks.